# 2 ids with 3 distinct groups in SAS

Tags: sas

hi I just wanted to know what would be the code in a data step for this outcome

I have the following:

[image]

and need the below:

[image]

please direct me to another page if this was answered previously...in addition how would I asked something like this in the future.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to do this in a data step? You might as well use `proc sql` for a Cartesian product.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select code, groupds
from (select distinct code from have) a,
     (select distinct groupds from have) b;
quit;
```

Here is how you can do it in a data step.

```
data want;
set have(keep=code where=(not missing(code)));
do i=1 to n;
set have(keep=groupds where=(not missing(groupds))) point=i nobs=n;
output;
end;
run;
```

The issue with this method is if you have a duplicate `code` or `groupds` a record will be created for the duplicate entry.

Comment: thanks yes I was thinking of doing it this way... but was wondering if it would be easier in a data step.

Comment: Here's an example of doing this in a data step, but I'd recommend just using `proc sql`: http://support.sas.com/kb/24/652.html